# How can I write a script to run after installation to stop GRUB from showing at boot (on a dual boot system)?)

Tags: grub2, 18.04, permissions

I am trying to set GRUB to not show at startup by using the command line. For this I try editing `/etc/default/grub` with `sudo`, but I get a `Permission denied` error as a response:

```
myuser@mysystem:~$ sudo echo "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true" >> /etc/default/grub
bash: /etc/default/grub: Permission denied
```

What I want to set:

```
sudo echo "" >> /etc/default/grub
sudo echo "# Hide Grub" >> /etc/default/grub
sudo echo "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0" >> /etc/default/grub
sudo echo "GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true" >> /etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub
```

Permissions of the file:

```
myuser@mysystem:~$ ll /etc/default/grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1211 Feb 12 20:00 /etc/default/grub
```

Shouldn't I be able to use `sudo` to edit this file? Why doesn't `sudo` give me the permission even though the file belongs to `root:root`?

**EDIT:**

Found out that the two above GRUB settings do not work for the desired goal. To still achieve GRUB not showing the following setting needs to be added to `/etc/default/grub` using:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true' >> /etc/default/grub"
```

Comment: You DON'T want to modify this file the way that you're doing it. In `terminal`, do `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`, modify the EXISTING lines that match what you need to change, save the file, then `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: @heynnema The problem with your approach is that it requires a human user in front of the screen. The reason I want to set the above is for a setup script after installation. I do not want the user having to set anything. Current solution is explained within the duplicate link, making use of `sudo bash -c "echo 'GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0' >> /etc/default/grub"`.

Comment: 1) your desired script is changing a system-level file, 2) no script necessary for something that only requires a one time manual edit, 3) you don't want to ADD lines to the grub file that ALREADY EXIST in the file.

Comment: Voting to reopen this question as it's about more than redirection.